# Problem with map function and for loop. Why is the result always "8"?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, map-function

I have a problem with this code. For every item in editorJSON, I want to access the id of the previous question and return it as "inputcontext" (e.g., for Question id 2 I want to access Question id 1, etc.). I tried to implement this with the following code, but the console.log() command always gives me "8".

```js
const editorJSON = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Question"
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Question"
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tipp"
  },
  4: {
    id: 8,
    "name": "Question"
  }
}

Object.keys(editorJSON).map((key, index) => {
  const inputcontext = () => {
    let inputcontext = "";
    var l = Object.keys(editorJSON).length;
    for (i = l; l < 1; i--) {
      if (editorJSON[i].name === "Question") {
        let inputcontext = editorJSON[i].id;
        return inputcontext
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(inputcontext())
})
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: How about if it is first object , what should be returned? There is nothing behind it

Comment: btw, the given structure has no previous part. it is not like a real ordered data structure like an array.

Comment: Okay got you , thanks for clarifying!

Comment: The wanted result is "2, 1". So for key "4" the result should be "2" and for key "2" the result should be "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the keys of the object and map the previous found key. This approach relies on the order of the keys with index like keys (32 bit positive integer numbers).

```js
const
    data = { 1: { id: 1, name: "Question" }, 2: { id: 2, name: "Question" }, 3: { id: 3, name: "Tipp" }, 4: { id: 8, name: "Question" } },
    previousQuestions = Object
        .keys(data)
        .filter(k => data[k].name === 'Question')
        .map((k, i, a) => [data[k].id, data[a[i - 1]]?.id]);

console.log(previousQuestions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since numeric keys are always iterated over in ascending order, you can loop over previous elements until reaching a question using `Array#map` which provides the original array as the third argument to the callback.

```js
const editorJSON = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Question"
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: "Question"
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tipp"
  },
  4: {
    id: 8,
    "name": "Question"
  }
};

const res = Object.keys(editorJSON).map((key, index, arr) => {
  let inputcontext;
  for(let i = key - 1; i > 0; i--){
    if(editorJSON[i]?.name === "Question"){
      inputcontext = editorJSON[i].id;
      break;
    }
  }
  return {...editorJSON[key], inputcontext};
});
console.log(res);
```